# Find scalar function so that vector field becomes source free

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-fields, divergence-operator

Give a function $f(r)$ with input $r = (x,y,z)^{\text{T}}$ and a vector field $V = f\cdot r$

How to determine $f$ so that $\nabla \cdot A = 0 \quad \textsf{(condition for solenoidality)}$

I have only reached as far:

$$\nabla \cdot (f\cdot r) = f\cdot \nabla \cdot r + r \cdot \nabla f = 0$$

which yields a complicated partial differential equation:

$$0 = 3\,f + x\cdot \partial_x\,f + y\cdot \partial_y\,f + z\cdot \partial_z\,f $$

Is there any symmetry to exploit?

Comment: Your PDE may be solved directly using the method of characteristics. Also I think you have a little typo in the last term, should it be $z\partial_z f$?

Comment: Shouldn't that be $3f$ in the last equation, since $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{r} = 3$ in 3 dimensions?

Comment: You are totally right I was typing this hastily